# Terraform: filter for Objects with specific Attribute

Tags: terraform

I have the following list as a local:

```
person = [
    {
      name = "bob"
      grants = [
        {
          principals = "bob@abc.com"
        },
        {
          group = ["users"]
        }
      ]
},
    {
      name = "alice"
      grants = [
        {
          principals = "bob@abc.com"
        }
      ]
}
]
```

I would like to filter only for (person) objects which have at least one element in grants which has an attribute `group`. So in the example the object bob should stay in while alice should disappear.

I tried something like this which didn't work

```
{ for b in(flatten([for person in local.persons : 
[{ "p_name" = person.name, "grants" = person.grants }] if contains(keys(person.grants), "group")])) : b.p_name => 
{ "p_name" = b.p_name, "grants"=b.grants } }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "it didn't work"? What specifically didn't work? Are there any errors? If so, add them to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your existing code you will get:

```txt
│ Error: Invalid function argument
│ 
│     if contains(keys(person.grants), "group")
│     ├────────────────
│     │ person.grants is tuple with 1 element
│ 
│ Invalid value for "inputMap" parameter: must have map or object type.
```

In your input the grants is a list, the `keys` functions expects a map or object.

---

For your code to work as is, your input will have to change the `grants` to a map something like:

```
locals {
  person = [
    {
      name = "bob"
      grants = {
          principals = "bob@abc.com"
          group = ["users"]
        }
    },
    {
      name = "alice"
      grants = {
          principals = "bob@abc.com"
        }
    }
  ]
}

output "filter" {
  value = {
    for b in(flatten([
      for person in local.person : 
      [{ "p_name" = person.name, "grants" = person.grants }]
      if contains(keys(person.grants), "group")
    ])) : b.p_name => { "p_name" = b.p_name, "grants" = b.grants }
  }
}
```

---

If you want to keep your existing input structure, then your if statement has to change to account for a list in the grants, the terraform code will be something like this:

```
locals {
  person = [
    {
      name = "bob"
      grants = [
        {
          principals = "bob@abc.com"
        },
        {
          group = ["users"]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name = "alice"
      grants = [
        {
          principals = "bob@abc.com"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

output "filter" {
  value = {
    for b in(flatten([
      for person in local.person :
      [{ "p_name" = person.name, "grants" = person.grants }]
      if contains(flatten([for g in person.grants : keys(g)]), "group")
    ])) : b.p_name => { "p_name" = b.p_name, "grants" = b.grants }
  }
}
```